# How can I recover docker container data

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-container

I use docker-compose to run an IDE. I created a project under /root/ inside this continer (by mistake, missed it), and /root is not mapped to host's /root. Thus the project there is gone after the container removed.
Looks like the container overridden after I added a mount point in the docker-compose.yml and executed "docker-compose up" , I don't know why it did it.
Is there any way to reach out the former container which overridden, specifically reach out "/root" in the old container?

Answer (score 0):

No. When you delete the container, you delete the changes made to the container filesystem. This is why interactively running commands in a container are discouraged in favor of adding them to the Dockerfile, and why volumes are used for persistent data.